# Pointing Jenkins to Use Another Plugin Repository

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Good afternoon,

As I understand Jenkins, if I need to install a plugin, it goes to [Jenkins Plugins](https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/)

The problem I have is Jenkins is installed on a closed network, it cannot access the internet. Is there a way I can download all of the plugins, place them on a web server on my local LAN, and have Jenkins reach out and download plugins as necessary? I could download everything and install one plugin at a time, but that seems a little tedious.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow some or all of the instructions for setting up an [artifactory mirror](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-configure-artifactory-as-an-internal-jenkins-update-site/) for the plugin repo.

It will need to be a http/https server and you will find that many plugins have a multitude of dependencies

Answer (score 0):

**The closed network problem:**

You can take a cue from the [Jenkins Docker install-plugins.sh](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/install-plugins.sh) approach ...
This script takes as input a list of plugins, and optionally versions (eg: `$0 workflow-aggregator:2.6 pipeline-maven:3.6.5 job-dsl:1.70`) and will download all the plugins and dependencies into a working directory.

Our approach is to create a file (under version control) and redirect that to the command line input (ie: `install-plugins.sh $(< plugins.lst`).

You can download from where you do have internet access and then place on your network, manually copying them to your `${JENKINS_HOME}/plugins` directory and restart the instance.

**The tedious list problem:**

If you only specify top-level plugins (ie: what you need), every time you run the script, it will resolve the latest dependencies. Makes for a short list, but random dependencies if they get updated at https://updates.jenkins.io. You can use a two-step approach to address this. Use the short-list to download the required plugins and dependencies. Store the generated explicit list for future reference or repeatability.